# create gmap3 polyline for each position

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps

I am collecting a load of history and add a map marker for each position, just wondering how i can also draw a polyline between each marker also?

```
jQuery.each(json, function(i, item) {
                var name = item.name;
                var userId = item.data.user;
                jQuery.each(item.data.data, function(i, nav) {
                    var ts = nav.timestamp;
                    var lat = nav.latitude;
                    var long = nav.longitude;

                    if (lat != null && long != null) {
                        addMarker(name, counts = counts + 1, ts, lat, long, userId);
                    }
                });
            })
```

i create a simple function to draw a polyline

```
 function addPolyline() {
    jQuery("#gMap").gmap3({
        action: 'addPolyline',
        options:{
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
        },
        path:[
        [37.772323, -122.214897],
        [21.291982, -157.821856],
        [-18.142599, 178.431],
        [-27.46758, 153.027892]
        ]
    });
```

}

but struggling to fugure out how i can draw the polyline from the foreach data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming in your json data you have already an array of points, or can construct one from parts of the data modify your `addPolyline()` function to accept an array as argument

```
    var polyArray=[
            [37.772323, -122.214897],
            [21.291982, -157.821856],
            [-18.142599, 178.431],
            [-27.46758, 153.027892]
            ];

    function addPolyline(polyArray) {
        jQuery("#gMap").gmap3({
            action: 'addPolyline',
            options:{
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2
            },
            path:polyArray
        }); 

    }
```

Not sure if you want to call this on each loop of your data or store data from each loop into an array and only call it once at the end.

If only calling it one time after loop:

```
    var polyArray=[];

    $.each(json, function(i,item){
        /* your other parsing code....plus add to polyArray*/                 
        polyArray.push( [ item.someValue, item.otherValue]);              

    });
    addPolyline(polyArray);
```